# What's the purpose of signing changesets in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, signature, gnupg

In Mercurial there's a special `.hgsigs` file [which](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FileFormats#A.hgsigs_.28ascii.29_.5Bgpg.5D)

> ...contains changeset signatures from the gpg extension, one per line.

What is this used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's useful only for asserting trust/signoffs on changesets.  If a changeset has been signed by one or more people you know that those people, or someone who posses their gpg credentials, signed those changesets.  Conceivably one could imagine workflows like, "Nothing can go on the production web server unless it has Jim's signature on it or you're fired" or "Everyone has to sign changesets they author so you know the author info wasn't faked."

It practice it's very seldom used since it means creating an extra changeset for each signature.